# How to remove the first character from SpannableStringBuilder

Tags: android, string

- Is it possible to remove the first character from
  SpannableStringBuilder.
- Similar to how we remove the first character in a string
- Also i am trying to find if first character is space ..is there a way
  to do it

Comment: use `replace` method (or simply `delete` - yes such method exists for convenience)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

You can use [**`spannableStringBuilder.delete()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html#delete(int,%20int))

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    String startText = " this is demo";
    SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView tvText=findViewById(R.id.tvText);
        TextView tvText1=findViewById(R.id.tvText1);
        spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(startText);

        StyleSpan firstStyleSpan = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);

        spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(firstStyleSpan, 0, spannableStringBuilder.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); // make first 4 characters Bold

        tvText1.setText(spannableStringBuilder);

        // first check here that  first character of spannableStringBuilder is a space or not
        if(spannableStringBuilder.charAt(0)== ' ')
            spannableStringBuilder.delete(0,1); // using spannableStringBuilder.delete() remove that first space from your spannableStringBuilder

        tvText.setText(spannableStringBuilder);

        Log.e("RESULT",spannableStringBuilder.toString());

    }


}
```

**LAYOUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

- the first `textview` display text contains space at starting of   `SpannableStringBuilder`
- the second `textview` display result after removing space from `SpannableStringBuilder`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use subSequence `builder.subSequence(0, b.length())`